# Error in own Intellij getter and setter template

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some field in this pattern: "_fieldName". Now I changed getter and setter template of Intellij to this:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
    ${field.name}##
#else
    #set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project).substring(1))))
    #if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
    is##
    #else
    get##
    #end
    ${name}##
#end
() {
return $field.name;
}
```

And I add ".substring(1)" to the line 8. But it doesn't work and I get this error in the picture. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: you have a space between get and Id()

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It is about space in first of line 8 to 14. And correct code is:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#else
public ##
#end
$field.type ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
    ${field.name}##
#else
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project).substring(1))))
#if($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
is##
#else
get##
#end
${name}##
#end
() {
return $field.name;
}
```